# bootstrap4 grid four rows on a page

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make an id card but after several research I found out there is really no diserable way to achieve column based label printing like that of MS Access Reports. So far I have managed to get the rows but the find it difficult to employ `page-break-after:always` since this involves bootstrap rows. Any help on achieving the cards to be four rows on a page at a time throughout the loop will be appreciated.
My code so far:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)){
    if($row['Guardian']){
        $guardian='<b>G: </b>'.ucwords(strtolower($row['Guardian'])).' - '.$row['Contact'];
    }else{
        $guardian='<b>G: </b>';
    }

    echo '
        <div class="col-md-6 pl-0 pr-0" style="height:8.425cm;border:1px dashed white;">
            <div style="height:2cm;background:#1579AA;">
                <h3 class="p-4 ml-2 text-white font-weight-bold;"><i class="fa fa-vcard"></i> Student ID Card<p><span class="text-white" style="font-size:8pt;">'.ucwords(strtolower($client)).' '.$rpt_addr_line2.'</span></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <h5 class="font-weight-bold mt-2 text-nowrap" style="color:#1579AA;margin-left:30px;">'.ucwords(strtolower($row['Surname'].' '.$row['Othernames'])).'</h5>
                    <p style="font-size:9pt;margin-left:30px;">'.$guardian.'</p>
                    <div id="std-'.$count.'-qr" class="mt-1" style="margin-left:30px;" class="border border-dark"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 mt-2 text-center">
                    <img class="border border-info p-1" style="height:120px;width:100px;" src="/uploads/students/'.$row['SID'].'.jpg" onerror="this.src=\'/_filx/_visualx/grafix/misc/avatar.png\'"/>

                    <img id="std-'.$count.'-bc"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12" style="height:1cm;background:#1579AA;" class="text-center">
                <p class="text-white p-2" style="font-size:8pt;">IN CASE OF EMERGENCY CONTACT MANAGEMENT ON '.$school_phone.'</p>
            </div><input type="hidden" id="std-'.$count.'-link" value="'.$rpt_link.'/verify-student.php?ref='.$row['ID'].'"/>
        <span id="std-'.$count.'-barcode" class="mhide">'.$row['SID'].'</span>';
    $count++;
    }
    echo '
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="total-students" value="'.$count.'"/>';
```

Comment: Try moving the styling in the 'style' attributes to a separate stylesheet, that makes your code much more readable. It can help if you can add a screenshot that explains what you have now and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

What is your query?and whats inside your data retreiving tables?
You shoud use a for loop inside the main data fetching for loop.

```
for(db data retrive array){
        for(filter for rows){
}
```

}

Comment: What are you trying to do ?